# XeTeX with LyX: English sentences inside math mode compile in the wrong order

Tags: math-mode, xetex, lyx, output

I'm having this strange problem when I compile documents containing math formulas with English text embedded in them.

For example, if my input on the LyX editor looks like this:

[image: IMG1]

Then the PDF output with XeTeX is this:

[image]

(The English words inside the text environment have their order flipped, but everything else remains the same)

I've looked around for quite a while and I haven't seen anyone else with this problem. Any suggestions?

LyX sample file:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
%%% Set Hebrew and English fonts
\setmonofont[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
%\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
% Proper font size in math mode.
\setmathrm[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Math}

%%% Another way is to set just the Hebrew fonts:
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
% consider using \usepackage{iffont}

%%% Sets both header and footer
\fancyhf{} % sets to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textup{\thepage}}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

%%% Some alternative styles
\ifcsname question\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{quesh}[thm]{×©××œ×”}
  \renewenvironment{question}{\begin{quesh}}{\end{quesh}}
\else
\fi
\ifcsname sol*\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem*{emphsol*}{×¤×ª×¨×•×Ÿ}
  \renewenvironment{sol*}{\begin{emphsol*}}{\end{emphsol*}}
\else
\fi

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{thm}{section}
\makeatother
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
theorems-ams-extended
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "David CLM"
\font_sans "default" "Hadasim CLM"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format pdf4
\output_sync 1
\output_sync_macro "\synctex=1"
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.5cm
\topmargin 3cm
\rightmargin 2.5cm
\bottommargin 3cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\bullet 0 2 5 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\text{firstword secondword thirdword fourthword}
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

TeX output of the sample file:

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David CLM}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hadasim CLM}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\synctex=1
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%%% Set Hebrew and English fonts
\setmonofont[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
%\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
% Proper font size in math mode.
\setmathrm[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Math}

%%% Another way is to set just the Hebrew fonts:
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
% consider using \usepackage{iffont}

%%% Sets both header and footer
\fancyhf{} % sets to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textup{\thepage}}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

%%% Some alternative styles
\ifcsname question\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{quesh}[thm]{×©××œ×”}
  \renewenvironment{question}{\begin{quesh}}{\end{quesh}}
\else
\fi
\ifcsname sol*\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem*{emphsol*}{×¤×ª×¨×•×Ÿ}
  \renewenvironment{sol*}{\begin{emphsol*}}{\end{emphsol*}}
\else
\fi

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{thm}{section}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\Pisymbol{psy}{183}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\LRE{
\[
\text{firstword secondword thirdword fourthword}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ask the lyx support. Or export to latex so that you can show the complete code (but reduce the document first).

Comment: Please make a minimal example .lyx (and .tex) file. Please read here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. Also, what LyX version are you using?

Comment: @scottkosty I'm using LyX 2.3.3. I've added the files to the question.

Comment: You've added a humongous file to the question, but it is not what you used to make that screenshot.  What is the smallest lyx file that can make that screenshot?  (And I assume there's a valid reason you're including Hebrew, but nothing you've shown indicates that reason.)

Answer (score 1):

You've run into this annoying bug in LyX: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7207. By the way (I don't expect you to have found the bug, it took me a long time to find it even though I knew that it existed), I found the bug by looking at [all LyX bugs with the component BiDi Support](https://www.lyx.org/trac/query?status=!closed&component=BiDi%20Support).